# Android Application for printing with Bixolon R200

Tags: android, printing

i am developing an android app for printing with Bixolon R200. i use bxlprint.jar's classes for my work. when i want print persian string like `سلام`,printer print weird character. i used UTF-8 and UTF-16 for encoding. can u help me plz ?

```
String PrintTextSample="سلام";

mBxlService.PrintText(PrintTextSample, BxlService.BXL_ALIGNMENT_LEFT, BxlService.BXL_FT_DEFAULT, BxlService.BXL_TS_0WIDTH | BxlService.BXL_TS_0HEIGHT,"UTF-16");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use Bixolon Character Map for Printing in other Languages

http://www.bixolon.com/upload/download/mobile%20printer_code%20pages%20manual_english_rev_1_00.pdf

Comment: how to use it? are there any examples?