# How To Print Persian Font by Bixolon Printer in Android Application?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application for printing with Bixolon SRP-330. My question is: "How could I print non-English characters, like Persian?"

I searched and I found I should use Bixolon character map but I don't know how to use that. I set Persian language with Bixolon SDK function but still words are separated and terms are reversed!

PS:
I found this question too:
[Android Application for printing with Bixolon R200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976079/android-application-for-printing-with-bixolon-r200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not find answer but i solve my problem in another way.
I Design A Layout XML File , Then Convert It To Bitmap Oject and Print BMP
This is my code :

```
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView() {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
            v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    int a = v.getMeasuredWidth();
    int b1 = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
```

}

This solution solved my issue,but Persian Worlds Are Bold !